# how to send email as anonymous authentication in powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I have never used Powershell before but my understanding is that it is best way of sending email on a Windows machine.

My network has provided me following details

```
SMTP server
Port
Authentication: Anonymous
From:
To:
```

Now when I am looked and researched internet I found we need username and password for sending email.

Is there any way I can send email using anonymous authentication with only server name provided and also include attachments?

Comment: [Try this](http://serverfault.com/questions/543052/sending-unauthenticated-mail-through-ms-exchange-with-powershell-windows-server/543115#543115)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I checked this but I don't understand there is no server name provided in script

Comment: The information you provided seems incomplete. In _general_ you need to authenticate to send email, but if you have a specific mail server in your local network which only permits outbound connections from inside your organization, that could work. But without the server name, this advice makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The mail server will do an anonymous relay depends on the configuration of the Recieve Connectors.So, Run the Send-MailMessage on the Exchange server and use 'localhost' as your SMTPServer, then  it won't go through a receive connector.
**Note:** Your email user should exist and part of a valid domain.Then you can send from **noreply@** or whatever you want to use.

```
send-mailmessage -From "noreply@example.com" -To "user01@example.com", "user02@example.com" -Bcc "user03@example.com" -Subject "Anonymous Mail Subject" -Body "Anonymous test Body" -SmtpServer 'localhost' -Port 25
```

*Note:*25 is the default smtp port.